# Can an L2 visa holder go back to their native country and resume their job wile waiting for the EAD work authorization?

Tags: usa, dependent-visa, l1-visa

I’m moving to California on an L1 visa soon. My wife will also be traveling with me. We have the following in mind:

1. She travels to US with me.
2. Applies for the EAD work permit and comes back to India.
3. Resumes her job in India until she actually gets the work permit.
4. Once she get’s the work permit, she quits her job in India, travels back to the US, and tries to find a job there ?

Is this legal ?

Comment: Work permits (EAD) are usually issued in 60 days (guaranteed within 90 days). I don't know about your situation but it doesn't seem worth it to return to India for just 2 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

US work authorizations is only relevant for when the person is in the US.

Comment: Hi, any help here please? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12052/requirements-for-b-and-l1-visa Thanks